# Check if array has any keys not in (another) array

Tags: php

This is probably a duplicate but I can't find my answer so...

What is the simplest way to do the following:

```
$valid_keys = ['a','b','c'];

$my_array = ['a'=>'foo', 'd'=>'bar'];

$my_other_array = ['a'=>'foo', 'b'=>'bar'];

array_has_invalid_keys($my_array, $valid_keys);
> true

array_has_invalid_keys($my_other_array, $valid_keys);
> false
```

Basically I want to check if my_array has any keys that are not in the valid_keys array

Comment: This is not a correct php syntax

Comment: My bad, should be better now

Comment: php also needs `;` :)

Comment: Can you tell I'm a pythonista at heart? lol

Comment: `$result = count(array_diff(array_flip($my_array), $valid_keys)) > 0 ? true : false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    
$valid_keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$my_array = ['a' => 'foo', 'd' => 'bar'];

$ret = array_has_invalid_keys($my_array, $valid_keys);

var_dump($ret);

function array_has_invalid_keys($my_array, $valid_keys) {
    $keys = array_keys($my_array);
    $invalid_keys = array_diff($keys, $valid_keys);

    return !empty($invalid_keys);
}
```

Comment: Won't this also return false if there are any keys in $valid_keys that aren't used in $my_array? I'll edit my question to be more clear, I want more of a 1-way comparison

Comment: phpdocs say, array_diff returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

Comment: try it with $my_other_array as per your example, and it will return false

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$valid_keys = ['a','b','c'];

function array_has_invalid_keys(array $array, array $valid_keys) : bool {
    foreach(array_keys($array) as $k) {
        if (!in_array($k, $valid_keys))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

array_has_invalid_keys(['a'=>'foo', 'b'=>'bar'], $valid_keys); // false
array_has_invalid_keys(['a'=>'foo', 'd'=>'bar'], $valid_keys); // true
```